# Website Footer wont stick to the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

Im trying to get a footer to stick to the bottom of my webpage but it floats only half way up. I've looked at a few examples and I cant see what im doing wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. My simplified code is shown below.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <!--Wrapper div for the main content-->
    </div>
        <!--Footer container-->
    <div class="footer">    
    </div>
</body>

</html>


--CSS-- 

body
{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
background-color: #1A1F2B;
min-width: 960px;

}

#wrapper{
min-height: 100%;
}

.footer{
position: relative;
margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 150px;
clear:both;
display: block;
background-color: #232A3B;
}
```

Comment: change position:relative; to position: fixed; for it to stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be at the bottom of the `document`:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If you want it to be at the bottom of the *viewport*:

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the footer div to be on the bottom of the page and span the entire width this would work:

```css
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #232A3B;
}
```

HTML5 also supports [the `<footer>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_footer.asp) which may make it easier for bots to process the information on your webpage.  To change that just use `footer {` instead of `.footer {` and change the HTML markup.